# How do I transpose, specific columns in a data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have the following problem statement-
[To sum up the values in the duplicate rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VsPh.png)

[and show the following out put data for EACH part number for 58 weeks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZABU3.png)

I managed to do the first part using groupby. I need help in figuring out the 2nd part.
Please advise.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).